# Stack Exchange API for Tags won't set has_more to True

Tags: support, tags, api

I have this request URL:

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/tags/python/top-answerers/all_time?page=1&pagesize=100&site=stackoverflow&filter=!9Z(-x.0nI

What I need is to have a pagination of users who answers with the tag `python`. The API will return only 20 items of users instead of 100, sigh. I don't have a clue how to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation for `/tags/{tag}/top-answerers/{period}`,

> Returns the top 30 answerers active in a single tag, of either all-time or the last 30 days.

But there's [a bug in the documentation](https://stackapps.com/questions/4735/top-answerers-top-askers-documentation-bug-number-of-results-returned-incorre) - it's supposed to be 20, not 30. And that's all you can get.

Unfortunately, there's no obvious (to me at least) method of retrieving *all* users who've ever been active in a tag via the API; you'd have to pull all the questions & answers for the tag with their authors & build that list yourself.

Comment: I would probably scrape than using their API. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: That's probably even slower... Check out [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/959363/top-users-by-tag)